# Replace a ID Value (of a Foreign Key) In A View By Its Value

Tags: c#, wpf, linq-to-sql, data-binding, datacontext

I have two tables, binded by foreign key CarrierID:

```
Carrier[CarrierID,CarrierName] 
CarrierID = 1, CarrierName = DHL
CarrierID = 2, CarrierName = Fedex
```

...

```
Vendor[VendorID, VendorName, CarrierID]  
VendorID = 1, VendorName =D-link , CarrierID=1  
VendorID = 2, VendorName = Netbes , CarrierID= 2
```

How can i show in the vendor gridView instead of CarrierID its value(that is :CarrierName)?
Example"

> ```
> View Vendor gridview
> 1 | D-link | DHL
> 2 | Netbes | Fedex
> ```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you mean this for LinqToSql:

```
var context = new DataContext();
System.Data.Linq.DataLoadOptions dlo = new DataLoadOptions();
dlo.LoadWith<Vendor>(v => v.Carrier);
context.LoadOptions = dlo;
```

...

```
gridview.DataContext/ItemsSource = /*my query result of Vendor*/ IQueryable<Vendor>.ToList();
```

**In your GridView**

```
{Binding Path=Carrier.CarrierName, FallBackValue=''}
```

The FallbackValue is set because Carrier can be null.

Comment: @slivermind what will be the "DataLoadOptions" since im getting error say that cant find the namespace

Comment: @ThivakaranSelvarajoo it's in System.Data.Linq, i've updated my answer.

Comment: The DataLoadOptions are there to have Carrier included, so if you dispose the DataContext they would still be there in case of LazyLoading.

Comment: @slivermind.. ok i found the solution... i just have to add this {Binding Path=Carrier.CarrierName, FallBackValue=''} ..And its works now..Thx.

Comment: @slivermind... I have one more problem right now. Im getting this error "ForeignKeyReferenceAlreadyHasValueException" when im trying to edit the carrier name.

Comment: @ThivakaranSelvarajoo How are you trying to edit the carrier name?

Comment: @Silvermind... select items from gridview and view in new wfp form.. All the fields can be edited and save but only when i try to edit the carriername in the vendor. Im getting this error.

Comment: @ThivakaranSelvarajoo Can you perhaps post this as a new question and put some example code in there? Xaml and codebehind? Because I think that would make it easier to solve your problem and this comment section won't get to long:)

Comment: @slivermind ..check here.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9885568/updating-error-using-ling-to-sql

Answer (score 1):

You could create a view in your database to accomplish what you want:

```
SELECT v.VendorName, c.CarrierName FROM Vendor v
  JOIN Carrier c ON c.CarrierId = v.CarrierId
```

Comment: Can you explain more since i use this code to view the carrier ...(<DataGridTextColumn Header="Carrier" Binding="{Binding Path= CarrierID}"/>)